# How to calculate the chiral condensate from wilson fermions in lattice qcd?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, eigenvalue, wilson-loop, lattice-gauge-theory

In lattice qcd, respective more specifically in (1+1)-dimensional massless schwinger model on a lattice, iam trying to reproduce the chiral condensate by using correct constructed wilson overlap fermions, no smearing.
According to the literature, iam calculating the determinant of the wilson operator for 1 degree of freedom, which seems to be working.
However, are there any computing advices,of how to get rid of appearing divergences as soon as the mass goes to 0?

Or more generic, what is the best approach to correctly use the calculated eigenvalues of the wilson overlap operator?

Answer (score 0):

The  problem in computing chiral condensates with Wilson fermions is that the physical $m=0$ limit is not obtained by setting $m=0$ in the action. This is because the $m=0$ Wilson action is not chiral invariant. Consequently much of early work on lattice chiral condensates was done with Kogut-Susskind staggered fermions.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a reference? Is it "Hamiltonian formulation of Wilson's lattice gauge theories" ?

Comment: You can try *Deconfinement and chiral symmetry restoration at finite temperatures in SU (2) and SU (3) gauge theories*
J Kogut, M Stone, HW Wyld, WR Gibbs, J Shigemitsu, SH Shenker, DK Sinclair
Physical Review Letters vol 50, p393 (1983)

Comment: To be honest, i don't see, how this could solve my issue. Let's speak about the quenched version (Nf=0). The condensate can be calculated as following: <sum(1/(x + m))> where the eigenvalues lambda were created in a complex manner by the overlap operator. x=1/(1/lambda -1/2). For m->0 I'm getting,   if I'm checking the data of the condensate in dependence of m , a divergence...

Comment: I gess the quenched Schwinger model is not very interesting as the  interesting stuff comes from the fermion loops.

Comment: I do see the same divergence for Nf=1. Here I'm using a reweighted condensate. The weight is the determinant of the overlap operator.

Comment: Are you staying sufficiently far from $m=0$ that we can still use Sokhotski-Plemelj to derive the Banks-Casher formula?  If you get closer than the mean eigenvalue spacing then you will have problems.

Comment: Iam very sorry, but I'm not familiar with the Banks-Casher formula, even though i stepped on it by mistake so to speak. Could you give some reference for the formula in my context?

Comment: Banks-Casher relates $\langle \bar \psi\psi\rangle$ to the density of eigenvalues of the Dirac determinant: T. Banks, A. Casher, *Chiral symmetry breaking in confining theories*, Nucl. Phys. {B169},  (1980) 103-125.